# How to reference a dll in the GAC that we don't have

Tags: c#, gac

In my application, I need to reference a dll that will be in the GAC on the target system, but which I don't have direct access to. I then also need to run dotfuscator on my application. NOTE: I actually *do* have access to the .dll, but that isn't how it will be in production, so I'd like to figure it out as if i didn't have it. 
Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: DLLs located in the GAC will automatically be loaded. Or have I totally missunderstood you?

Comment: You want to develop against the DLL without it actually being on the development machine?

Comment: @David, no: _"NOTE: I actually do have access to the .dll, but that isn't how it will be in production"_.

Comment: It will be loaded at runtime, but I don't(or won't) have the dll to compile and obfuscate my application.

Comment: @David I don't have to develop without it on the machine because I am working on the SDK(which is what the .dll is) as well, but other users *will* have to, so it would be helpful if I knew how to do this as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a reference to the DLL and set `Copy Local` to `False`. This way the application will be published without the DLL and expect it to be present on the clients' system, which it will be: in the GAC.

Read [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx) for more information.

Comment: When I do this, my obfuscation step fails since I assume it is looking for the assembly and can't find it. I may be able to gacutil /install on my development machine, but that won't fly on the build machine...

Comment: It would have saved both you and me time if you told that already in your question. I would not _assume_ anything. Are you sure the error in the obfuscation process is caused by the obfuscator not able to find this assembly?

Comment: Yes. If I set Copy Local to true it works. However, when I do this and then delete the .dll later so that it doesn't get deployed to the target system, my application does not run. It is like it will only work if the .dll is in the target folder and it isn't looking in the GAC.
Sorry I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: Then I think the real solution to your problem would be to research (or contact the creators of the software about) the possibility to let your obfuscation software work with GAC'ed DLL's.

Comment: I *can* use GAC'ed DLLs with dotfuscator, but I *cannot* install .dll's to the GAC on our build system.